# Почему в ${.....} число можно передать но нельзя строку .... мол ' не определен'

Tags: javascript

Почему в `${.....}` число можно передать но нельзя строку .... мол ' не определен'

```js
let productContainer = document.querySelector('.product-container')

let data = [
    {   id:1,
        name:'Samsung',
        price:3232
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:'Nokia',
        price:3434
    },
    {   id:3,
        name:'Sony',
        price:36667
    },
]


function CartRender(param){
console.log(param)
}


for(let item of data){
    productContainer.innerHTML += `
    <div class='product-item'>
    <span>${item.name}</span>
    <span>${item.price}</span>
    <button onclick = CartRender(${item.name}) class='btn'>add</button>
    </div>
   `
}
```

```html
<div class="product-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не в том, что это строка, а в вашей синтаксической ошибке. `CartRender(${item.name})` -- в этом куске вы говорите интерпретатору вставить значение `item.name` в строку. Интерпретатор вставляет, и вы получаете, например, `CartRender(Sony)`. Соответственно интерпретатор считает, что вы ему передаете неопределенную переменную. Ваша проблема решается добавлением кавычек, чтобы интерпретатор воспринял передаваемое значение как строку:

```js
let productContainer = document.querySelector('.product-container')

let data = [
    {   id:1,
        name:'Samsung',
        price:3232
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:'Nokia',
        price:3434
    },
    {   id:3,
        name:'Sony',
        price:36667
    },
]


function CartRender(param){
console.log(param)
}


for(let item of data){
    productContainer.innerHTML += `
    <div class='product-item'>
    <span>${item.name}</span>
    <span>${item.price}</span>
    <button onclick = CartRender('${item.name}') class='btn'>add</button>
    </div>
   `
}
```

```html
<div class="product-container"></div>
```